# How do I hide the sound effect icon in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When I add a sound file to my PowerPoint presentation, it shows up in my presentation as a small speaker icon.

[image: Sound File Icon]

How can I hide the sound icon when playing my presentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using **Microsoft PowerPoint 2010, 2013 or 2016**:

> 1. Click the audio clip icon <sub><sub><sub>[image: Sound icon - 2010]</sub></sub></sub>.
> 2. Under **Sound Tools**, on the **Playback** tab, in the **Audio Options** group, select the **Hide During Show** check box.

If you are using **Microsoft PowerPoint 2007**:

> 1. Click the audio clip icon <sub><sub>[image: Sound icon - 2007]</sub></sub>.
> 2. Under **Sound Tools**, on the **Options** tab, in the **Sound Options** group, select the **Hide During Show** check box.

[image: Option for 'Hide during show']

Source: [Add audio to your PowerPoint presentation - Microsoft Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-audio-to-your-PowerPoint-presentation-c3b2a9fd-2547-41d9-9182-3dfaa58f1316)

Answer (score 0):

### In all versions of PowerPoint

1. Select the sound icon so that the selection box appears.
2. Drag the sound icon so that it is no longer on the slide.

This technique is not very useful for grouped objects, as moving the visible area can cause the sound to reappear on screen. However, as sub-objects of groups cannot have separate animations applied to them (including the Play and Pause actions) this will probably not have much of a detrimental effect.